# How to add an id column to identify read_html() tables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, iteration

Consider the following sites ([site1](http://pastebin.com/vpnGqn5X), [site2](http://pastebin.com/FbAFGbfR), [site3](http://pastebin.com/LqZWxFSP)) which have a number of different tables.

I am using [read_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-html) to scrap the tables into a single table as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
links = ['site1.com','site2.com','site3.com']

def process_url(url):
    return pd.concat(pd.read_html(url), ignore_index=False)   

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
df = pd.concat(pool.map(process_url, links), ignore_index=True)
```

With the above procedure I am getting a single table. Although is what I expected, it would be helpful to add a flag or a "table counter", just to not lose the reference of the table (e.g. which row belongs or corresponds to which table). So, how to add the number of the table to a row?.

Something like this, the same single table, but with a `table_num` column:

```
    Bank Name   City    ST  CERT    Acquiring Institution   Closing Date    Updated Date        table_num
1   Allied Bank     Mulberry    AR  91.0    Today's Bank    September 23, 2016  October 17, 2016        1
2   The Woodbury Banking Company    Woodbury    GA  11297.0     United Bank     August 19, 2016     October 17, 2016    1
3   First CornerStone Bank  King of Prussia     PA  35312.0     First-Citizens Bank & Trust Company     May 6, 2016     September 6, 2016   1
4   Trust Company Bank  Memphis     TN  9956.0  The Bank of Fayette County  April 29, 2016  September 6, 2016   2
5   North Milwaukee State Bank  Milwaukee   WI  20364.0     First-Citizens Bank & Trust Company     March 11, 2016  June 16, 2016   2
6   Hometown National Bank  Longview    WA  35156.0     Twin City Bank  October 2, 2015     April 13, 2016  3
7   The Bank of Georgia     Peachtree City  GA  35259.0     Fidelity Bank   October 2, 2015     October 24, 2016        3
8   Premier Bank    Denver  CO  34112.0     United Fidelity Bank, fsb   July 10, 2015   August 17, 2016     3
9   Edgebrook Bank  Chicago     IL  57772.0     Republic Bank of Chicago    May 8, 2015     July 12, 2016   3
10  Doral Bank  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     4
11  En Espanol  San Juan    PR  32102.0     Banco Popular de Puerto Rico    February 27, 2015   May 13, 2015        4
12  Capitol City Bank & Trust Company   Atlanta     GA  33938.0     First-Citizens Bank & Trust Company     February 13, 2015   April 21, 2015  4
13  Valley Bank     Fort Lauderdale     FL  21793.0     Landmark Bank, National Association     June 20, 2014   June 29, 2015   5
14  Valley Bank     Moline  IL  10450.0     Great Southern Bank     June 20, 2014   June 26, 2015   5
15  Slavie Federal Savings Bank     Bel Air     MD  32368.0     Bay Bank, FSB   May 3, 2014     June 15, 2015   5
16  Columbia Savings Bank   Cincinnati  OH  32284.0     United Fidelity Bank, fsb   May 23, 2014    November 10, 2016   6
17  AztecAmerica Bank   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 6
18  En Espanol  Berwyn  IL  57866.0     Republic Bank of Chicago    May 16, 2014    October 20, 2016    6
```

For instance, if there are two tables in site1, the function must assign `0` to all the rows of `table1`, and with regards to `table2` in `site1` the function must assign `1` to all the rows of `table2`.

On the other hand, if `site2` has two tables, the function must assign `3` to all the rows of `table1` and `4` to `table2` for all the tables that live in `site2`.

Also, is it possible to use [assign()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) or other method to get the reference of each row (e.g. the table of provenance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your `process_url()` function as follows:

```
def process_url(url):
    return pd.concat([x.assign(table_num=i)
                      for i,x in enumerate(pd.read_html(url))],
                     ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help MaxU. This was very near, the problem is that this approach is actually assigning the row numbers wrong. For instance, for all the tables in `site1` is assigning them `0`. On the other hand, if `site1` has two tables (`table1` and `table2`) the procedure must assign `0` to all the rows of `table1`and `1`to all the rows of `table2`. Thank you very much for your time!