# Is there a way to speed up this webscraping iteration? Pandas

Tags: pandas, web-scraping

So I'm collecting data on a list of  stocks and putting all that info into a dataframe. The list has about 700 stocks.

```
import pandas as pd

stock =['adma','aapl','fb'] # list has about 700 stocks which I extracted from a pickled dataframe that was storing the info. 

#The site I'm visiting is below with the name of the stock added to the end of the end of the link
##http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=adma
##http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl
```

I'm just extracting one portion of that site, evident by [-2] in the code below

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in stock:
    df = pd.read_html('http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t={}'.format(i), header =0)[-2].set_index('SEC Form 4')
    df['Stock'] = i.upper() # creating a column which has the name of the stock, so I can differentiate between stocks
    df2 = df2.append(df)
```

It feels like I'm doing a few seconds per iteration and I have around 700 to go through at the moment. It's not terribly slow, but I was just curious if there is a more efficient method. Thanks.

Comment: Check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641166/how-to-add-an-id-column-to-identify-read-html-tables), probably this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is *blocking*, you don't proceed with retrieving the information from the next url until you are done with the current. Instead, you can switch to, for example, [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) which is based on `twisted` and working asynchronously processing multiple pages at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I've never heard about  `Scrapy`. Is this the goto  web-scraper now?  I was recommended to look into `Requests` a little while back but I'm presuming `Scrapy` is more popular now